# Picking values from previous response and sending the data in corresponding number of blocks in subsequent requests in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract values from a json response of previous request and pass values to variables and use them in subsequent request bodies. Here the catch is, only set of 20 values need to be passed in one subsequent request. So the count of subsequent requests keeps on increasing/decreasing based on the size of response. For example if 100 values/sets are received in response then count of subsequent requests will be 100/20 = 5 requests with set of 20 values in each request.
And the body of last request sampler will contain less than 20 values if not left with 20 records(if count of sets received in response is not exact multiple of 20).
Records will follow the same sequence , means first 20 records in first sampler, 21-40 in second sampler and so on.
So accordingly count of subsequent samplers/requests will increase or decrease depending on the response size.

**Request 1 Response**

[ { "Specialization": "Computer Science", "DegreeProviderId": "DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-785252d8f804", "Type": "Update", "GId": "Party:e5329b74-a88b-df59e1d7de9e", "TeacherId": "TeacherProvider:7e7f5628-663f-42e1-a6e6-13cb0bd34e3d", "UpdatedDate": "2021-05-31T13:07:21", "FirstName": "Tibet", "NewData": [ "SSN : 878-00-1250", "FullName : " ], "CollegeName": "TTT", "LastName": "China", "InProgress": true }, { "Specialization": "Agriculture Science", "DegreeProviderId": "DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-7852u65f804", "Type": "Update", "GId": "Party:e5329b74-a88b-df7865rfdt-de9e", "TeacherId": "TeacherProvider:7e7f5628-663f-42e1-a6e6-13cb0bd34e3d", "UpdatedDate": "2021-05-31T13:07:21", "FirstName": "Auf", "NewData": [ "SSN : 548-00-9890", "FullName : " ], "CollegeName": "AAA", "LastName": "Usa", "InProgress": true },

I have to pass value of DegreeProviderId in subsequent request like below

**Sampler/Request body1**

[{"Id":"DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-785252d8f804","Type": "Update", "IsValued": false, "Comment":""},
{"Id":"DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-7852u65f804","Type": "Update", "IsValued": false, "Comment":""},
.....
.....
.....
20}]

**Sampler/Request body2**

[{"Id":"DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-785252d8f804","Type": "Update", "IsValued": false, "Comment":""},
{"Id":"DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-7852u65f804","Type": "Update", "IsValued": false, "Comment":""},
.....
.....
.....
20}]

**Sampler/Request body3**

[{"Id":"DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-785252d8f804","Type": "Update", "IsValued": false, "Comment":""},
{"Id":"DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-7852u65f804","Type": "Update", "IsValued": false, "Comment":""},
.....
.....
.....
20}]
.
.
.

..
..

**Sampler/Request body N**
....
....

Total number of records in response is not a constant, its changing continuously. Subsequent Request count depends of count of records received in previous response. So I need to write a code to capture the values of DegreeProviderId, Type, IsValued and Comment values and use them in subsequent requests in number as explained above. Please help me to handle this scenario. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) to extract the values from the response and then iterate with the values with a [For Each controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is going for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following code:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())


def partition(array, size) {
    def partitions = []
    int partitionCount = array.size() / size

    partitionCount.times { partitionNumber ->
        def start = partitionNumber * size
        def end = start + size - 1
        partitions << array[start..end]
    }

    if (array.size() % size) partitions << array[partitionCount * size..-1]
    return partitions
}

def chunks = partition(response, 20)

1.upto(chunks.size(), {
    def payload = []
    chunks.get(it - 1).each { entry ->
        payload.add([DegreeProviderId: entry.DegreeProviderId, Type: entry.Type, isValued: false, Comment: ''])
    }
    vars.put('request_' + it, new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
})
```

It will generate [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like `${request_1}`, `${request_2}`, etc. containing up to 20 entries, the variables can be used in the [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Hi Dmitri,  Thanks for the help. But this code is generating request_1 with empty body.  request_1=[
    
] . Ideally it should generate 3 requests , request_1,request_2 and request_3 as there are 60 records in response, but it is generating 1 request only that too empty. No errors observed in Jmeter logs. I checked this in Debug Sampler response data. Could you please look into this issue.

Comment: I cannot "look into the issue" without seeing the full response and where did you put the JSR223 PostProcessor